# "Some things will be known, but others will not", or "... will not be"?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives

Which is the correct sentence?

> - Some things will be known, but others will not.
> - Some things will be known, but others will not be.

Comment: The second, I guess.

Comment: Both are fine. They are both derived from the sentence "Some things will be known, but others will not be known" through the process of [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase_ellipsis).

Comment: "Which is the correct sentence" suggests a presumption that one of them is not correct. What could be the reason you thought so? They are both correct, as Peter Shore said, and mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks ! I do not know. I thought that the two following where fine: Some things will be known, but others will not. and Some things will be known, but others will not be known. But I was unsure about third alternative: Some things will be known, but other will not be. It sounds a little strange to me, that is all. But yes, elipsis is the magic word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are OK, and mean the same thing:

> Some things will be known, but others will not be known.
>
> Some things will be known, but others will not be.
>
> Some things will be known, but others will not.
>
> Some things will be known, but not others.